# How to insert multiple rows using variable in Oracle database through PHP?

Tags: php, oracle, variables, insert

How to insert multiple rows using variable in Oracle database through PHP?
My query-:

```
$qry6= "INSERT INTO sample(name , id , qty , PRICE , tax) VALUES ".$result_product1.";";
```

where

```
$result_product1 = (shirt,1,20,300,100),(pant,2,50,400,75),(tie,5,50,100,25);
```

So how to pass multiple rows in oracle through php?
I get from forum as query should be-:

```
INSERT ALL into sample(name , id , qty , PRICE , tax values (shirt,1,20,300,100)
           into sample(name , id , qty , PRICE , tax values (pant,2,50,400,75)
           into sample(name , id , qty , PRICE , tax values (tie,5,50,100,25);
```

So plz help me that How can I convert my query in this oracle accepted format....
Plz guide me...

Comment: $result_product  is a variable which stores string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know much more about insertion in oracle.
But as per your question this may help you...

```
$result_product1 = str_replace( "),(", ") into sample(name , id , qty , PRICE , tax) values (", $result_product1);
```

And your final query will be...

```
$qry6= "INSERT INTO sample(name , id , qty , PRICE , tax) VALUES ".$result_product1.";";
```

Check this...